# Trying to submit the checked data into database

Tags: php

****I'm trying to get submiitted value in database.After getting the value from a particular table i want to store the checked value into another table with the same columns.How to add the values that come from database while submitting after the checked valueHere's my code****

form.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
        <head>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
          <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <form action="insert.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Sec</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sec" id="sec">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            <button type="submit" name="getdata" class="btn btn-default">Get</button>
        </form>

        </body>
    </html>
```

insert.php

```
<?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","input");
// inserting data
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $sec=$_POST['sec'];


        if($name !=''||$sec !=''){ 


            $query = mysqli_query($con,"insert input_form(Name,Sec) values ('$name', '$sec')");
            echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";

        }
        else{
            echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";
        }
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['getdata'])){

        $query1 = mysqli_query($con,"select * from input_form");
        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
            ?>
            <ul class="form-get">
                <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" ><li><?php echo $row1['Name'];?><?php echo $row1['Sec']; ?>  </li>
            </ul>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <button name="present">Submit</button>
        <?php
    }
        ?>

        <?php

    if(isset($_POST['present'])){
        $checkbox=$_POST['chk'];
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($checkbox);$i++){
            $query2=mysqli_query($con,"insert into present(Name,Sec) values ('".$checkbox[i]."')");
        }
    }
    ?>

<?php

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to archive. Please try to be more clear

Comment: That's a lot of code. What exactly is not working with it? What have you tried to debug that problem?

Comment: I do dot see checkbox inside form.

Comment: after getting the values from database i want to submit only the checked values in another table while i click submit button

Answer (score 0):

you should set a status for checked value to "1" and "0" to unchecked to store into database.Make a condition that if the variable is checked and have status to "1" then it will be submitted to database otherwise not.
 here you can make a condition.

First  of all you have missing a tag for check box in the form

```
  <label for="checkbox">check</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="chk" id="chk">
```

**here you can post the checkbox status**

```
$chk=$_POST['chk'];
```

////////////**create a column for check box also to make it easy.**/////

```
 if(isset($_POST['present'])){
    $checkbox=$_POST['chk'];
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($checkbox);$i++){
      if($checkbox===1){
        $query2=mysqli_query($con,"insert into present(Name,Sec,checkbox) values 
              ('".$checkbox[i]."')");
              }
                 } 
                 }
```

hope it may help you.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: still the checked data is not getting inserted in the database

Comment: Did you added the if condition  and column in database?